# QMediaResource::audioBitRate return 0

Tags: c++, qt

This code is part of my project.

`audioBitrate()` always returns `NULL(zero)` while other media players perfectly show the bitrate.

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaResource>
QMediaResource audioFile(QUrl::fromLocalFile("song.mp3"));
int audioBitrate = audioFile.audioBitRate();
QString bitrate = QString(QString::number(audioBitrate));
QMessageBox::information(this,"title",bitrate,"ok");
```

Why does this always return zero ?

Comment: Try to output the bit rate again during playing file

Comment: again same result zero....

Comment: Could it be that audoBitRate doesn't work on mp3s with variable bit rate?

Comment: What are _other media players_ that perfectly show the bitrate?

Comment: Note that  `audioBitRate()` returns zero if the bit rate is _unknown_

Comment: So, I would opt to set the bit rate manually with `setAudioBitRate()` to verify .. then the question would be why bit rate is _unknown_

Comment: clementine(built in Qt),banshee,vlc.....that perfectly show the bitrate